# How tomcat-servlet-api is linked to servlet-api?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, servlets

On a online course, I have this following project's pom's piece:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.30</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

This project is supposed to run on Tomcat7, and it does. I noticed it excluded `servlet-api` from `jstl-api` and `jstl-impl` and it uses `tomcat-servlet-api` as `provided`. This are my Tomcat's libs:

[image]

Since it just have `servlet-api.jar`, where does the mapping between this two different names occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wherever servlet-api classes are used, the servlet-api classes included in the tomcat-servlet-api are used instead. the tomcat-servlet-api wraps the servlet-api classes.

Comment: I know, I asked about how and where it used servlet-api instead of tomcat-servlet-api as on pom

Comment: wherever servlet-api classes are used, the servlet-api classes included in the tomcat-servlet-api are used instead. make sense?

the tomcat-servlet-api literally wraps the servlet-api classes. do you know what a wrapper is? i don't want to be condescending, i'm not sure what your experience level is.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. You were not rude at all, I'm after an answer, and you explained. Could you please edit your answer adding info about wrapper and my specific question so I can accept it? Thanks